# How to add a badge to android notification inside the pull down menu?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I saw that google's gmail has a notification that shows with a small badge and i was wondering if that is something i can add to my notifications.  Here is an example:

[image]

See the RED little badge hanging off the icon. is that something i can utilize. I am targeting the following in gradle:

```
 minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: This may give you an idea: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
```